# Problem with downloading dependencies gt-epsg-hsql

Tags: geotools, deployment

Few days ago I started training with maven repository on www.geotools.org. Right now I have a problem with downloading dependencies gt-epsg-hsql. My Eclipse tell me that kind of Error "Offline/Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:13.2". I asked uncle google but he didn't know. So now I'm asking You what can I do? My pom file looks like that:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org.geotools
    tutorial
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    tutorial
    http://repo.opengeo.org/

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>13.2</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Could somebody help me?:)

Comment: Write a mail to geotools-users mailing list. The repositories at OpenGEO/Boundless has a new arrangement and everything is not yet found where it should.

Comment: Actually just reading the geotools-user list will do

Answer (score 1):

As @user30184 says in the comments there have been some issues with the Boundless repository so try changing the address in your pom to

```
 <url>https://boundless.artifactoryonline.com/boundless/main</url>
```

In general when working with [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) it makes sense to be subscribed to at least the [geotools-user](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/geotools-gt2-users) list.